# REST Jersey server JAX-RS 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm calling this method and getting a 500 back from it.

In the debugger I'm able to step though it all the way to the return statement at the end. No problem, r is populated as expected after Response.build() is called, the status says 200 OK.  But that's not what ends up getting produced. I've even told eclipse to break on any Exception.

```
@GET
@Path("/getAllAppMessagesAsXML")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response getAllAppMessagesXML(@QueryParam("applicationId")  String applicationId){
    ResponseList list = new ResponseList();
    ArrayList<XmlMessageBean> xmlmessages = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        List<AppMessage> messages =  //Gets from a database
        for(AppMessage m : messages){
            XmlMessageBean xm = new XmlMessageBean();
            xm.setId(m.getId());
            xm.setApplicationId(m.getApplicationId());
            xm.setMessageBody(m.getMessageBody());
            xm.setMessageLevel(m.getMessageLevel());
            xm.setMessageTitle(m.getMessageTitle());
            xmlmessages.add(xm);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("ERROR Failed to save Message AppMessageService.saveAppMessage()", e);
        Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }   
    list.setList(xmlmessages);
    Response r = null;
    try{
        r = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(list).build();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return r;
}
```

XmlMessageBean.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="AppMessage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlMessageBean {

    @XmlElement
    private Long id;
    @XmlElement
    private String applicationId;
    @XmlElement
    private String messageTitle;
    @XmlElement
    private String messageBody;
    @XmlElement
    private String messageLevel;

    public XmlMessageBean(){
    }

//getters and setters

}
```

ResponseList.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ResponseList")
public class ResponseList {

    public ResponseList(){
    }

    @XmlElement(name="list")
    private List<XmlMessageBean> list;

    public List<XmlMessageBean> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<XmlMessageBean> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

I've got this all running in a jersey.servlet.ServletContainer 
I'm stumped.  I can't figure out how to get it to produce any kind of error message other than a generic 500. I've tried setting up an exception mapper as some other posts have mentioned but this also isn't picking anything up.

Comment: Have you enabled logging for Jersey and your servlet container?

Comment: I have.  The logs are also silent.

Comment: Have you done a simple hello world round trip to verify network, firewall, etc?

Comment: I'm doing some diving seeing IllegalAnnotationException: Class has two properties of the same name "list"

Maybe I don't have my exception mapper configured right. I'd think I wouldn't have to work so hard for get that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `IllegalAnnotationException: Class has two properties of the same name "list"`

Look at your two model classes `XmlMessageBean` and `ResponseList`. Do you see any difference? The main difference (and the cause for the error), is the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation (or lack there of). JAXB by default will look for the public properties (JavaBean getters/setters). So that's one property. But then you define another property by using the `@XmlElement` annotation on the field. The reason it works for `XmlMessageBean` is that it overrides the default public property lookup by changing it to `XmlAccessType.FIELD`

So you can simply annotate the `ResponseList` with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` and it should work. You could also simply get rid of all the `@XmlElement` annotations, and get rid of `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`, and it will still work, as it will look up the JavaBean properties. Generally, for me I only use the `@XmlElement` annotations when I need to change the name of the property, and just put it on the getter, for example.

```
private String messageBody;

@XmlElement(name = "body")
public String getMessageBody(){
    return messageBody;l
}
```

Other than that, I normally leave out the annotation, and also the `@XmlAccessorType` annotation, and just let it resolve to the default behavior.